# How do you Solve a Mixed Inhomogeneous Dirichlet and Homogeneous Neumann Boundary Conditions of Standard Heat Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have been given a standard heat equation $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0$$ with $u(t,x)$ and the intial condition $u(0,x) = 0$ and the boundary condtions $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,0)=0, u(t,1)= \sin(\omega t)$.

Due to having an inhomogeneous boundary condition separation of variables method fails, however, the method I was taught for inhomogeneous boundary conditions is for $$u(t,0)=f(t) \\ u(t,1)=g(t)$$ and then using $$u(t,x) = u_p(t,x)+v(t,x)$$ where $$u_p(t,x)=xg(t)+(1-x)f(t)$$  How do I go about modifying this so that I can solve the initial-boundary value problem?

Comment: Let $u(x,t) = v(x,t) + u_{p}(x,t) = v(x,t) + 1 - x^{2} + \sin(\omega t)$.

Comment: @mattos Thank you for this suggestion.  After working since posting this, I ended up just using $\sin(\omega t)$, which I am not sure is correct.  Is it possible to use what I went with?

Comment: If you set $u_{p} = \sin(\omega t)$ then your boundary conditions for are \begin{align} 0 &= \partial_{x} u(t, 0) \\
&= \partial_{x} v(t, 0) + \partial_{x} (\sin(\omega t)) \\
\implies \partial_{x} v(t, 0) &= 0 \\
\sin(\omega t) &= u(t, 1) \\
&= v(t, 1) + \sin(\omega t) \\
\implies v(t, 1) &= 0 
\end{align} So yes, your choice makes the boundary conditions for $v$ homogeneous.

Comment: You can solve the problem directly using the substitution $u(x,t) = e^{i \omega t}v(x)$ after transforming using complex numbers $sin(\omega t) = e^{i \omega t}$ where $v(x)$ is an unknown function most likely complex